# Accessing Java BigQuery Tools in Maven with Nexus

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm at the very beginning of building a bigquery uploader in Java. Goal is to download a full twitter stream and uploading that into hourly buckets, then processing these in Dremel for a topic detection and tracking project. This is all Java on MacOSX in Eclipse Juno, plus Maven with a local Nexus proxy.

I'm stuck at the starting gate; finding and compiling a simple Java sample that authenticates and uploads a CSV file. Closest I've found is bigquery-appengine-sample, although I don't see why I need appengine for a bigquery project. Will explore that later.

Problem is, the project won't build in maven. No error flags shown in eclipse, but often eclipse error flags are unreliable. The pom shows a red eclipse flag on this element:

> com.google.apis
>         google-api-services-bigquery
>         ${bigquery.version}

Maven install fails with

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project bigquery-appengine-sample: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.google.api.client:bigquery-appengi
>   ne-sample:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.google.apis-samples:shared-sample-appengine:jar:1.3.2, com.google.api
>   s:google-api-services-bigquery:jar:v2-rev18-1.7.2-beta: Failure to find com.google.apis-samples:shared-sample-appengine:jar:1.3.2 in ...SOF won't allow URLs... was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed
>    or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Nexus proxies are defined for http://mavenrepo.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/ and http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/ (both set as SNAPSHOT). Neither of these seem seem to be working. Browse storage and indexes both come up empty (just an archetype catalog). However Browse Remote does seem to work AFAICT; shows a maven repository tree that seems complete.

So my question: how to build bigquery samples in Java with maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I can observe from outside google, the answer to the question as posed is:

- No java example is available (yet?) that covers uploading. The sample
  at the address in the posted answer only covers querying sample data
  that is already present in the account.
- The closest sample to what I need  seems to be the 
  command line and python samples. But using them is complicated by the fact that 
  each sample is hard-wired
  to work only with specific maven dependency versions, samples aren't being updated
  when new API versions are released, and older API versions are often not available via
  maven.
- The maven problem seems to originate from using a wildly idiosyncratic version 
  numbering system (such as the v2beta1-rev17-1.7.1-beta-beta example
  above). Maven relies on strict adherence to convention, and such
  version numbers definitely don't comply. For rapidly changing
  beta code, version numbers should be major#.minor#.micro-SNAPSHOT as documented in the maven book. NO EXCEPTIONS or maven breaks as explained in the comments.

URGENT REQUEST: Please provide a *working* java sample that covers all BigQuery features, particularly step 1; uploading data. Please bundle the samples with the API code to ensure they stay in sync. And adopt maven conventions throughout, including retroactively.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few non-App Engine Java samples here: http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-tools/source/browse/samples/java/

I use Sonatype's Maven plugin, and at minimum, your pom.xml should look like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.google</groupId>
  <artifactId>google</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>google</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.3-beta</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-bigquery</artifactId>
      <version>v2-rev19-1.7.2-beta</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
      <repository>
      <id>google-api-services</id>
      <url>http://mavenrepo.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>    
  </repositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example code. Very helpful. But I'm getting the same problem as before after importing as maven project and building. Neither eclipse or maven is able to find google-api-services-bigquery. Might something be wrong in the google repository perhaps?

Comment: Hey Brad: So, just to test, I created a new Eclipse project (I'm using using the Nexus Indexer Archetype catalog, skipped archetype selection, and used the pom.xml above which I just updated). I could not reproduce the errors you are seeing. Are you sure that your project is updating dependencies? (project menu->Maven->Update Dependencies?)

Comment: I think I see what's going on in some if perhaps not all cases. Some samples have dependencies that really aren't available via maven. I've been using bigquery-cmdline-sample to work around the lack of a java equivalent (I've posted a request to fix that). Its pom depends on google-api-services-bigquery v2-1.3.3-beta which doesn't' exist. Changing the version to v2-rev12-1.6.0-beta fixes the build. Is there something you can do to either keep referenced dependencies available, or (better) update the samples to point to available versions, it would be a huge help. This is too painful now.

Comment: Also, could you verify that the binary jar file name is correct for /com/google/apis/google-api-services-bigquery/v2-rev12-1.6.0-beta/google-api-services-bigquery-v2-rev12-1.6.0-beta.pom. The beta- beta.jar in the file name smells fishy; i.e. com/google/apis/google-api-services-bigquery/v2-rev12-1.6.0-beta/google-api-services-bigquery-v2-rev12-1.6.0-beta-beta.jar

Comment: Also maven is notoriously particulalr about version names. Idiosyncratic version names (are three betas, a v2, and a rev17 in v2beta1-rev17-1.7.1-beta-beta really conveying anything useful???). Why not name them acc'd maven standards; major.minor.micro-SNAPSHOT; 1.7.1-SNAPSHOT in this case.

Comment: Got it to load finally by changing the pom as follows: <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-bigquery</artifactId>
            <version>v2beta1-rev17-1.7.1-beta</version>
            <classifier>beta</classifier>
            <!--<type>pom</type>-->
        </dependency> Notice the <classifier>beta</classifier>

Comment: Based on what I'm seeing, the only way your build could have worked is you have the missing versions cached in your ~/.m2 repository. Did you erase it before trying this build?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work after testing out the url http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo for these libraries. It does not allow browsing so nexus will attempt to index this repo and fail. When this happens Nexus blocks access to this repo and thus local build fails due to missing dependencies.

To alleviate this I changed two settings in Nexus for this repository.

- Download Remote Indexes = false
- AutoBlock Enabled = false

With this set I was able to build and download dependencies correctly.

Note: We also use GCM-Server Repo for Android and it had this same issue, the same solution was applied and we were able to cache the new dependency.